# React Native Android Gradle Fail

Tags: android, gradle, react-native

I'm trying to get a ReactNative Android app up and running, but after going through the initial setup guide, I get the error:

> Error:Failed to find target with hash string 'android-26' in:
>   /Users/nicholasstephan/Library/Android/sdk
>   Install missing platform(s) and sync project

I don't want to install and use SDK v26, React Native specifically uses v23.0.1. I'm not sure where that reference to v26 comes from.

Any ideas where that reference to android-26 could be coming from?

Answer (score 0):

Either you are saying that it should compile with Android 26 (targeting and compiling could have two different target versions) or some of your dependencies are asking for that specific version.

Check all your node-modules for build.gradle and settings.gradle files.

Answer (score 0):

This is due to maven repo URL, I faced same issue in android studio As it can't find `android-26` but it can `26`

I suggest to check

1 . `youProject/android/app/build.gradle`

2 . `youProject/android/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml`

and search for `'android-26'` string and make it just `26` 
In my case it was  `compileSdkVersion 'android-26'` 
so I change it to  `compileSdkVersion '26'`